# React doesn't render useEffect at the frist time

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Learning hook, tried to read a JSON file using `useEffect`, intended to `setState` for the array and render to list, but the program doesn't seem to run `useEffect` at the first time.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  getData()
})

const [people, setPeople] = useState([])

const getData = () => {
  Json.forEach(person => add(person))
}

const add = (person) => {
  const peopleCopy = people
  const newPerson = {
    firstName: person.firstName
  }
  peopleCopy.push(newPerson)
  setPeople(peopleCopy)
}
```

Full exaple: https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-architecture-s0jpd?file=/App.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `useEffect` itself works fine. You are just mutating the existing state (the `people` array) and so the component does not rerender.

The `const peopleCopy = people` does not really create a copy. You just create a variable pointing to the original people array.

But even if you create a new array at that point, it would not work correct as you would be resetting it on each iteration

You would need to re-write the `add` to something like

```js
const add = (person) => {
  const newPerson = {
    firstName: person.firstName
  };
  setPeople((currentPeople) => [...currentPeople, newPerson]);
};
```

and you also need to add `[]` as the dependencies to `useEffect` to avoid running it on each re-render.

```js
useEffect(()=>{    
  getData()
}, [])
```

So, altogether: https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-mcclintock-ogrzn?file=/App.js

Comment: Thanks for your thorough explanation (and editing of my question)!

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix `app.js` like this.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Json from "./data.json";

const App = () => {
  const [people, setPeople] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    setPeople(Json.map((person) => ({ firstName: person.firstName })));
  }, []);

  const list = people.map((e, i) => <div key={i}>{e.firstName}</div>);

  return (
    <div>
      {people.length}
      {list}
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```